# Syntax error by using ruby-youtube-dl

Tags: ruby, git, github, rubygems, gemfile

i'm new to this site and also in programming. Actually i'm learning Ruby.
In my first experiments i would like to download a file from Youtube. I decided to use ruby-youtube-dl.
I parse ARGV0 to $url.
Then i'm using:

```
FileUtils.cd("#{$musicdir}/#{$folder}") do
  YoutubeDL::Downloader.download_audio("#{$url}")

end
```

But that one produces that output:

```
sh: -c: Zeile 0: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort `('
sh: -c: Zeile 0: `/home/sascha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/ruby-youtube-dl-0.0.5/bin/youtube-dl.py --no-progress --extract-audio --audio-format=mp3 --output=/tmp/%(stitle)s-%(uploader)s-%(autonumber)s.mp3'
/home/sascha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/ruby-youtube-dl-0.0.5/lib/ruby-youtube-dl/downloader.rb:9:in `download_audio': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/sascha/RubymineProjects/ruby_script_collection/youtube_dlhelper/lib/youtube_dlhelper.rb:86:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/sascha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:125:in `chdir'
    from /home/sascha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib64/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:125:in `cd'
    from /home/sascha/RubymineProjects/ruby_script_collection/youtube_dlhelper/lib/youtube_dlhelper.rb:84:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The full sourcefile is placed there: http://pastebin.com/jAwjHanw

Maybe anyone can help out?

Comment: the part if url `%(stitle)s-%(uploader)s-%(autonumber)` contains parentheses, instead of plain text, or may be braces. From where are the code parts?

Comment: I used it via require 'ruby-youtube-dl'. This is the used gem: https://github.com/bnmrrs/ruby-youtube-dl/blob/master/lib/ruby-youtube-dl/downloader.rb

Comment: Try to fix the gem locally(even just remove parentheses, and #), and then may be, you need to report the issue to developers, but from now store logs, checkout gem, in the `Gemfile` set link not to git, but with `path` key.

Comment: Did you fix it locally?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes it was great. I'm working on this in a local testing branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked into the log, and it seems to be a bug. You can do the following steps the solve, or partially solve the problem:

1. Check out gem:

   ```
   $ cd ~/git
   $ git clone https://github.com/bnmrrs/ruby-youtube-dl.git
   ```
2. Specify the path folder in your project's **Gemfile** that will point to the newly checked out gem:

   ```
   gem 'ruby-youtube-dl', :path => '~/git/ruby-youtube-dl'
   ```
3. Try to fix the gem locally, for example by removing parentheses, and # chars, and replacing them with constants. Of course it will be a workaround.
4. In case if you are developing a gem or rails app, you shell to publish you changes to web, and you are able to do that by forking the *gem* on *github*, pushing you changed into you version branch:

   ```
    $ git clone git://github.com/yourname/ruby-youtube-dl.git
    $ cd ruby-youtube-dl
    $ git branch fixbranch
    $ git checkout fixbranch
    # do your changes...
    $ git push origin fixbranch
   ```
5. Use your changes as the main gem *version*. In this case you are need to change your `Gemfile` for example as follows:

   ```
   gem 'ruby-youtube-dl', :git => 'git://github.com/yourname/ruby-youtube-dl.git', :branch => 'fixbranch'
   ```
6. In case if your changes are not workaround you can open a pull request on *github* to commit your changes into the mainstream.

If you are unable to solve the problem even with a workaround, it will be beast to report the issue to the gem developers [here](https://github.com/bnmrrs/ruby-youtube-dl/issues), supplying the error logs unto them.

Comment: Thank you very much for helpig out. I implement this into the next branch.

Comment: @saigkill so you can accpect the answer